# How to get current year in the Postman script

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I have a requirement to get current year in the Postman pre-req script.

I'm planning to get the current date, then convert the date to string and apply sub-string to get year value

I would like to know, is this the right way of doing it, or is there any pre-defined function available to do it?

Comment: if any of the answers helped you do keep upvote and accept them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to get current year :

```
new Date().getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no pre-defined function to get year alone may be you can try like below,

```
const moment = require('moment');
pm.globals.set("timestamp", moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
```

Then reference {{timestamp}} where ever you need it.
check the [link](https://dannydainton.com/2018/05/21/hold-on-wait-a-moment/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

To get year -

```
var moment = require('moment');
console.log("timestamp", moment().format("YYYY"));
```

or even without using moment library -

```
console.log(new Date());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentYear=new Date().getFullYear();
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("currentYear" ,  currentYear);
```

This worked for me.